# Multistep user registration using profile2

Tags: users, forms

How can we create a multistep user registration form in drupal 7 using profile2 module.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Field group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group)

> Fieldgroup will, as the name implies, group fields together. All
>   fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap
>   their fields together. Fieldgroup comes with default HTML wrappers
>   like vertical tabs, horizontal tabs, accordions, fieldsets or div
>   wrappers.

Available group types

- Fieldsets
- Horizontal tabs
- Vertical tabs
- Accordions  Divs
- **Multipage steps:** Note: This is only client side.

And i found a nice tut [here](http://grasmash.com/article/building-multistep-registration-form-drupal-7)